# Can't get input box to appear under a combo box

Tags: html

I have a combo box and then another combo box underneath it that is hidden. I would like to show an input box underneath as well but the only way it appears underneath is when I show the hidden combo box.

```
<SELECT NAME=cbCode2 onchange = "LoadSlaveData_onChange(document.Main, this, 'FMLA_GetReasons\'010469\',1,%,\'10/21/2013\',\'10/21/2013\', NULL', document.Main.CBQUAN2,'%'); DisableDept('2');">
    <OPTION  value=''  selected >&lt;Select Type&gt;</option>
    <OPTION  value='R'>Travel</option>
</SELECT>

<SELECT NAME='CBQUAN2' id='CBQUAN2' style=display:none>
    <OPTION value=''  selected >&lt;Select Reason Code Test&gt;</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' disabled='disabled' NAME='cbDept2' ID='cbDept2' VALUE=' ' SIZE='8'   MAXLENGTH='10'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the display method to block for the input box:

```
<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' disabled='disabled' NAME='cbDept2' ID='cbDept2' VALUE=' ' 
SIZE='8' MAXLENGTH='10' style = "display: block">
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/76Qc7/)

Answer (score 2):

Input elements are inline by default. Change it to block instead.

```
input {
    display:block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9rAt8/)**